# Whole div clickable except for 2 nesting divs

Tags: jquery, html

I have a job div, and need it all clickable.

```
$(".job").click(function(){
    window.location=$(this).find("a.link").attr("href"); 
    return false;
});
```

However there are 2 other divs (`.apply` and `.like`) that have their own actions. And shouldnt be taken to the link when clicked. When either of these 2 divs are clicked, how do I avoid being brought to the whole div's link?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use Javascript to do this, try using this simple CSS:

```
.job a {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This way your link should work as a link, but the clickable area should be the whole size of it's parent element.  No reason to detect the click via Javascript, not to mention this will abandon people who don't support it.  The solution is easily done in good ole' vanilla CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Target the specific divs onclick and then override using preventDefault:

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Once the default is prevented you can add a custom action.